# Model instance fixtures not persisted on the database

Tags: django, pytest, pytest-django

I have a test class with two methods, and want to share a saved model instance between both methods.

My fixtures:

```
@pytest.fixture(scope='class')
def model_factory():
    class ModelFactory(object):
        def get(self):
            x = Model(email='test@example.org',
                      name='test')
            x.save()
            return x
    return ModelFactory()

@pytest.fixture(scope='class')
def model(model_factory):
    m = model_factory.get()
    return m
```

My expectation is to receive only the `model` fixture on (both) my test methods and have it be the same, persisted on the database:

```
@pytest.mark.django_db
class TestModel(object):

    def test1(self, model):
        assert model.pk is not None
        Model.objects.get(pk=model.pk)  # Works, instance is in the db

    def test2(self, model):
        assert model.pk is not None     # model.pk is the same as in test1
        Model.objects.get(pk=model.pk)  # Fails:
        # *** DoesNotExist: Model matching query does not exist
```

I've verified using `--pdb` that at the end of `test1`, running `Model.objects.all()` returns the single instance I created. Meanwhile, psql shows no record:

```
test_db=# select * from model_table;
 id | ··· fields
(0 rows)
```

Running the `Model.objects.all()` in pdb at the end of `test2` returns an empty list, which is presumably right considering that the table is empty.

1. Why isn't my model being persisted, while the query still returns an instance anyway?
2. Why isn't the instance returned by the query in the second test, if my `model` fixture is marked `scope='class'` and saved? (This was my original question until I found out saving the model didn't do anything on the database)

Using `django 1.6.1`, `pytest-django 2.9.1`, `pytest 2.8.5`

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tests must be independent of each other. To ensure this, Django - like most frameworks - clears the db after each test. See [the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/testing/overview/#the-test-database).

Comment: Thank you Daniel, I suspected this was the case. @rnevius I've been using the `--reuse-db` option to pytest to avoid database recreation, but the test runner still flushes the data between individual test runs, which was the thing confusing me I suppose `--keepdb` would have the same effect.

Answer (score 0):

By looking at the postgres log I've found that `pytest-django` by default does a `ROLLBACK` after each test to keep things clean (which makes sense, as tests shouldn't depend on state possibly modified by earlier tests).

By decorating the test class with `django_db(transaction=True)` I could indeed see the data commited at the end of each test from psql, which answers my first question.

Same as before, the test runner ensures no state is kept between tests, which is the answer to my second point.

Answer (score 0):

Scope argument is in this case a bit misleading, however if you would write your code like this:

```
@pytest.fixture(scope='class')
    def model_factory(db, request):
        # body
```

then you would get an error basically saying that database fixture has to be implemented with 'function' scope.

I would like to add that this is being currently worked on and might be an killing feature in the future ;) [github pull request](https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest-django/pull/258)